# I want to check whether a string is palindrome

Tags: c++11, for-loop, if-statement, palindrome

```
char s[100];
//char t[100];
int count = 1;
int j=0;
int x,i;
cin >>s;
x=strlen(s);
//cout <<x <<endl;
cout <<s[j] <<endl;
i=x-1;
cout <<s[i] <<endl;
for (int i = x-1; i <= 0; i--)
{
    if (s[j] != s[i])
    {
        count = 0;
    }
    j++;

}
if ( count  )
{
    cout <<"YES";
}
else
{
    cout <<"NO";
}
return 0;
```

I Want to whether a given string is palindrome or not. Whats wrong with this code? i am expecting it to print YES if a palindrome is being input and NO if the string is not a palindrome. But it always prints YES. There are no errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: The condition `i <= 0` is false from the start. The loop never runs.

Comment: `for (int i = x-1; i <= 0; i--)`: This loops as long as `i <= 0` which only happens if you enter an empty or one-character string. Thus the for loop never runs and `count` is always `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is never entering that `for loop` since the condition `i = x-1 and i <=0` wont be true well `assuming your string is not empty`, then there is no need to keep a count variable since as soon as the strings are not matching you can print NO and exit the code.

You can implement it like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char s[100];
    int x,i,j=0;
    cin >>s;
    x=strlen(s);
    i = x-1;
    cout <<s[0] <<endl;
    cout <<s[i] <<endl;
    for (int i = x-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s[j] != s[i])
        {
            cout <<"NO";
            return 0;
        }
        j ++;
    }
    cout <<"YES";
    return 0;
}
```